# Get all Succeeded Jobs with Hangfire Monitoring API

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, hangfire

I am using the `JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi()` in Hangfire to get a count of all succeeded tasks. To do so I am using the following function:

```
var api = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();
var succeededJobs = api.SucceededJobs(0, int.MaxValue);
```

However, this seems to only return the most recent days worth of Succeeded jobs. In my case it returns `95` but if you look at my dashboard I see much more.

[image]

Is there a way through the MonitoringApi to pull all historical job data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set the `JobExpirationTimeout` property for each job to prevent it from being removed from the storage too early.

This can be done with an `IApplyStateFilter`.

See :
https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-configure-the-retention-time-of-job/34

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, do you know of any issues with adding an indefinite timeout? I have several jobs, 36k right now but around 1k everyday. Will having so many jobs cause any performance or memory issues?

Comment: @A.Hasemeyer depending on the storage, setting an infinite timeout might be an issue. The storage is not designed to be  long time log storage system.